# Visualizing a Deformation Retraction

Tags: general-topology

It's known that there exists a deformation retraction from the space $\mathbb{R}^3$\ $S^1$ to $S^2 \wedge S^1$, and I thought I had a visualization for it, but now it seems discontinuous.  Can anyone help out with describing (or even better constructing explicitly) this map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The space $\mathbb R^3\setminus S^1$ is obtained by rotating a closed half-plane with a puncture in it. The latter space can be retracted onto semi-circle plus a diameter. The rotation of semi-circle plus a diameter creates $S^2$ plus a diameter. Now it is time to lose the rotational symmetry: we contract the Eastern hemisphere into a point (sorry, guys). The result is $S^2\wedge S^1$.

Comment: +1 Very nice , Leonid ! (Especially since I live in the Western hemisphere...)

Comment: perfect, I can see it now!  Thanks so much!